# Show tooltip for part of a label when hover

Tags: jquery, html

I have a label as below:

```
<label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="AB">Text A/ Text B:</label>
```

I wish to show a tooltip when hover over "Text B" but not when hover over "Text A".  I tried using jquery but it would get the whole label and show the tooltip even when I hover "Text A".

```
 $("label:contains('Text B')").prop("title", function ()
{
    return "Text B ";
});
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: It seems to work just fine for me

Comment: you probably have to split the two parts into two spans and apply your control depending on span id instead of the text content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply wrap inner text with `span` and apply proper `title`

```html
<label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="AB">
    <span title="Text for FIELD A">Text A</span>
    / 
    <span title="Text for FIELD B">Text B</span>:
</label>
```

---

Using jQuery

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.control-label').each(function() {
    var parts = $(this).text().split('/');
    $(this).html(
      "<span title='" + parts[0] + "'>" + parts[0] + "</span>" +
      "/" +
      "<span title='" + parts[1] + "'>" + parts[1] + "</span>"
    );
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="AB">Text A/ Text B:</label>
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that the label is actually generated by a method in server side and it is costly to split the label into two parts. Therefore, I need to do the tooltips at the client side and show it.

Comment: the label content is usually `text`, but that's not always the case, it can contain nested html elements such as span, ... So it's safer to deal with all text nodes only. Here is a safer implementation https://jsfiddle.net/pd6ypssn/ looping through all text nodes ***recursively*** is a different problem, may also be taken into account. ( =)) the OP should do this).

Answer (score 0):

html like,

```
<label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="AB">Text A / <span> Text B: </span> </label>
```

and js ,

```
$("label span").prop("title", function ()
{
    return "Text B ";
});
```